# marquee text of textview in actionbar not marquee anyone after setText

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a `ActionBar` with a `TextView`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:text="This will run the marquee animation forever"
            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingTop="20px"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

in my Activity:

```
    ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
    TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
```

//the marquee text work before the following line

```
    mTitleTextView.setText("My Own Title");
```

//the marquee text not work after above line

```
    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the text, add the following

```
    mTitleTextView.setSelected(true);
    mTitleTextView.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **mTitleTextView.setSelected(true);** after setText("Your text"); ?